# "expected a declaration" in QtCreator on valid code

Tags: c, qt-creator, libopencm3

I'm working in a C project with QtCreator (yes it's primarily for C++, but so far it worked OK for C).

Now I'm getting a red underline on a valid code that compiles fine:

[image]

It's basically [this](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3-examples/tree/master/examples/stm32/f3/stm32f3-discovery/usb_cdcacm) unchanged libopencm3 example project for a Virtual COM port.

Can you see some problem in the code, perhaps not fatal, but what could make the editor think it's an error?

I tried substituting `struct usb_device_descriptor` with an equivalent typedef, but that didn't help.

Error on the second line says "expected }, got .". The closing `}` is annotated as "extra ;`

Here's how the struct is declared:

```
/* USB Standard Device Descriptor - Table 9-8 */
struct usb_device_descriptor {
    uint8_t bLength;
    uint8_t bDescriptorType;
    uint16_t bcdUSB;
    uint8_t bDeviceClass;
    uint8_t bDeviceSubClass;
    uint8_t bDeviceProtocol;
    uint8_t bMaxPacketSize0;
    uint16_t idVendor;
    uint16_t idProduct;
    uint16_t bcdDevice;
    uint8_t iManufacturer;
    uint8_t iProduct;
    uint8_t iSerialNumber;
    uint8_t bNumConfigurations;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Comment: looks like this bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1902

Comment: ah okay, so best option is to just ignore it for now. thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround:

Change the value for "C" to Clang in this settings page:

[image]

(As m.s. points out in the comments, you may have to [enable the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346956/expected-a-declaration-in-qtcreator-on-valid-code/33348353?noredirect=1#comment54548150_33348353) first)

Comment: How do you enable "clang" in QtCreator? Those options are greyed out for me (Qt Creator 3.5.1, installed via online installer on Linux)

Comment: I installed it from the Arch repository. Do you have clang (and the other optional dependencies) installed?

Comment: I have clang++-3.7 installed on Ubuntu 14.04 via the llvm repository (http://llvm.org/apt/); which other dependencies are there? is there any list you could point me to?

Comment: sure, this is an info page for the package I have: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qtcreator/
I have clang 3.7.0-4, qtcreator 3.5.1-1

Comment: I found out the reason (maybe it was obvious, but not me): The `ClangCodeModel` has to be activated through `Help->About Plugins` ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/gYKncZr.png)). After a restart of QtCreator the above mentioned option is available.

Comment: Interesting, I don't remember going to that setting dialog at all. I've added a note in the answer for future googlers.